# Restore Git shortcut from Eclipse Mars in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: eclipse, git

The now old Mars version of Eclipse had a nifty shortcut (Ctrl-#) where you could quickly commit all untracked changes with very few keystrokes and no use of the mouse.

In Eclipse Neon this has been changed and requires a ton of additional clicking around and mouse-handling to accomplish the same thing.

Where has the old shortcut gone, can it be restored?

Comment: You'll have to be much more specific.  The same binding works fine in Neon for me.  However, I believe it used to bring up a separate dialog, and now it just makes the "Git Staging" view visible.  Your behavior may vary if you're not using git, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to uncheck `Use Staging View to commit instead of Commit Dialog` under *Team -> Git -> Committing*.
Not sure when this became the default.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTsOP.png)